# "cannot POST error" with node js and reactJS

Tags: javascript, php, html, reactjs

I'm making a small website using ReactJS and I encountered a weird problem, I have a contact form in the page but when I click "send" in order to send an email, I get the following error:

[image]

Which doesn't make sense because in theory, I have the correct route in the action tag of the form, this is a portion of my code:

```html
<form action="../php/mailto.php" method="POST">
       My form is here    
</form>
```

I also tried with "./php/mailto.php"

Also, this is how I have the folders arranged:

[image]

And while the form itself is in the contactForm file, it is a component that is called in App.JS.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

By the way, this is the php file, which should be ok:

```php
<?php
    log("Hi i'm in php");

    $_to_email_address=[my email];
    $subject="test";
    $message="TEST TEST TEST";

    mail($to_email_address,$subject,$message);
?>
```

Forgot to add, in console I get a 404 error, basically it doesn't find the file

Comment: what does your network tab show when you post: what is the actual server response for both the [preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) (`OPTIONS`) and the post itself?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans it shows error 404 for the post, I cannot see the options tab (I'm in Opera GX)

Comment: How are you running your React app? Something like webpack probably doesn't know how to serve a PHP file without a local web server running.

Comment: @velvetkevorkian I'm using node, more specifically npm start to start the server

Comment: indeed, php scripts will only run when run _by_ PHP, as far as Node knows, they're just inert text files. If your server isn't a PHP server, your PHP script won't do anything. But, if you're running a Node server, why are you writing PHP at all? Write Node code to do what you need?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Well, I got a sort of "test" task and one of the tasks is a contact form, I never understood ff my superiors wanted for the form to outright send an email or only wanted the front end, and I assumed that he wanted for it to send an email.

Comment: as a professional developer: don't assume, verify what is needed and don't spend time on what isn't. However, even if they need emails sent: why are you writing PHP code in a Node project?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Well, the test itself said "Necesitamos que haga un landing page en React" (we need you to make a landing page with react) and in the job interview I talked about my little (few months) experience with ReactJS. And I just sent an email asking if they just want frontend or also a send email function. As of now I'll just make the site prettier

Comment: Especially for a job interview, asking questions about what the requirements are means you're showing you're thinking about what needs to be done, instead of just assuming what needs to be built. Usually that's a plus. If all they're asking for a React landing page, then it's highly unlikely they need mailing functionality, but even if they did: they're asking for React code, which is JS and runs on Node/the browser. They're not asking for PHP code (which is PHP, and can only run on the server).

Comment: Then what I have as of now is a finished project, guess I'll wait for a confirmation mail...and if I don't receive it just send the code as is explaining that it is just frontend in reactjs (and instructions of how to run it)

Thank you @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Comment: As long as your React project _doesn't contain PHP code_ =)

Comment: I almost sent the repository with that pesky php folder with that "mailto.php" script, deleting it and commiting it now, thanks for the heads up